# PowerApps Patch statement to clear a lookup column

Tags: powerapps, dataverse

I have a canvas app that refers to two Dataverse tables: Households and People.

People has a lookup column, "Household".

When the PeopleList gallery (gal_PeopleList) is filtered by household, an 'x' icon becomes visible in each record which I'd like to remove the person from that household (I have a confirmation routine in place to prevent accidental removals).

I can't get the Patch statement to work. If it's generating an error, I'm not seeing it. But it's not clearing the "Household" lookup column in the "People" table.

Here's my failing code:

```
Patch(People,
    First(Filter(People,Person=gal_PeopleList.Selected.Person)),
    {
        Household: Blank()
    }
);
UpdateContext({ShowPopup:false});
```

Searching around has shown me how I can change that "Household" to another record, but not how to clear it or set it to blank or null.

Grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

For mulit-select lookup column - OnSelect of your button you could create a blank collection. Then patch that blank collection into your lookup column:

```
ClearCollect(colBlank, {Id:0, Value:Blank()});
Patch(People,
    First(Filter(People,Person=gal_PeopleList.Selected.Person)),
    {Household:colBlank}
)
```

Or try this if it is **not** a multi-select lookup. You'll have to build out the schema to match your lookup column:

```
Patch(People,
    First(Filter(People,Person=gal_PeopleList.Selected.Person)),
    {Household:{
       Id: 0,
       Value: Blank(),
       Owner: Blank()
     }
    }
  )
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the idea. I've run into a couple of issues.

First, the Patch statement wants the data types to match ("Household" is of type "Record" and "colBlank" is of type "Table"). So I tried `{Household: First(colBlank)}` as that last argument for `Patch`.

But then it says the schema doesn't match. Must I create a collection with every last column??? Because Dataverse has created a couple dozen columns there.

Specific error: `Missing column. Your formula is missing a column 'Owner' with a type of 'Polymorphic'.`

Comment: I updated my response, the second code might work better since Im assuming your lookup column is not multi-select. (multi-select lookup column would require a table, single select would require just a record).

Comment: Thanks JBerg, I think I'm getting closer. You are correct that it's single-select. The code is happier that I'm giving it a record, but it is indeed demanding matching schema. One field it's demanding is `Active` which is of type of `OptionSetValue`. 1) The "Active" column is not actually a required column (does that matter?); 2) I give it `"Active"`, `'Active'`, and `'cre9a_Active'`, and it's not happy whatever. I also try different types of values, including using the `Choices` function, but I can't seem to come right.

Comment: Try setting "Active" to 0. More info here on data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/reference/entities/lookupmapping